# Cannot increase video element width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

So I have a case like this

[image]

As you can see the video does not fill the entire width of the element.

This is what my html looks like -

```
<div class="webcam"/>
    <div class="control-container">
</div>
```

The video element gets created through the use of a javascript webcam library -

https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs

```
var that = this;
Webcam.set({
    width: this.options.width,
    height: that.options.height,
    image_format: 'jpeg',
    jpeg_quality: 100,
    force_flash: false
});
Webcam.attach('.webcam');
```

This is what the video elem looks like

[image]

Right now, the width and height are 562 and 344, which is also the width and height of the containing element. I have tried to make these bigger, but all that happens is the white space gets larger, rather than the actual live viewer.

What should I do?

Comment: edit your code in print screen and write it

Comment: how unhelpful - what are you even saying?

Comment: :) I am saying people need to see the small text I wanted to help nevermind

Comment: ohhh - I thought you meant something entirely different - is this the text in the chrome console?

Comment: just copy paste it right click and choose edit html then copy and put it here

Comment: Look at this page [Click] (http://daverupert.com/2012/05/making-video-js-fluid-for-rwd/) i think it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code

```
.webcam {
  width: 100%    !important;
  height: auto   !important;
}
```